# Invalid binary character when transmitting ProtoBuf-net messages over AWS SQS

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, amazon-sqs

I'm using Protobuf-net (https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) to serialize my class, and then trying to transmit this via amazon SQS.

When I do that I get this error:

```
Amazon.SQS.AmazonSQSException: Invalid binary character '#xC' was found in the message body, the set of allowed characters is #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF].
```

which is pretty self-explanatory.

Has anyone got a good solution on how to get this working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only these characters are allowed in the message body: see the [SendMessage API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/Query_QuerySendMessage.html).

To send any binary content, you have to encode it, e.g. using [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). The message is then larger, but contains only ASCII characters, which is even more strict than Amazon requires.

We are using this approach e.g. in the [softwaremill-common](https://github.com/softwaremill/softwaremill-common/blob/master/softwaremill-sqs/src/main/java/com/softwaremill/common/sqs/Queue.java) library to send a serialized Java object.